# IAM Role to allow IAM users to create only VM Instances and Disk in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-iam

I have given Compute Instance Admin(v1) Role with Type

```
 1 compute.googleapis.com/Disk and
 2 compute.googleapis.com/Instance
```

If the above roles are given then the user is not able to create anything, If I remove both conditions then the user is able to create everything like machine image, snapshot. I want to restrict to only instance and disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such a role to fulfill your requirements right away, but you can go ahead and create a [Custom IAM Role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#iam-custom-roles-testable-permissions-console). I'd also recommend checking the IAM roles and permissions [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam) for Compute Engine itself.

Then, while there's no such a role for you, you can start by creating a custom role based on e.g. `Compute Viewer` role. You'll have to add IAM permissions related to `compute.disks` and `compute.instances` in order to allow using and creating VMs and disks.

There's no easy way to determine which permissions are required, but you can start creating VMs in the Web UI and check the audit logs for missing permissions. Here's ones that are definitely required (if your role is based on the Compute Viewer):

```
compute.disks.create
compute.disks.resize
compute.disks.use

compute.instances.reset
compute.instances.resume
compute.instances.setMetadata
compute.instances.start
compute.instances.stop
compute.instances.suspend
compute.instances.update
compute.instances.use
compute.instances.setServiceAccount

compute.subnetworks.use
compute.subnetworks.useExternalIp
compute.networks.use
compute.networks.useExternalIp
```

Also, you'd need to give your user the `Service Account User` role, cause the VMs are created with a particular service account (the Compute Engine default service account is used by default).